# Private Api in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone

Can we use private method in MPMoviePlayerController
e.g: 
-(void)setOrientation:(int)orientation animated:(BOOL)value;
for playing movie in portrait mode. Did apple approve private api?

Answer (score 0):

No, Apple does not approve use of private APIs of any kind, if they find that you've been using private APIs, they will reject your application.

Comment: Thank You..
so what should i do to play movie in Portrait mode.

Comment: Other than using the private *setOrientation* method, you cannot.